# How do I prerender a namespaced react component using the react-rails gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

(Note: I'm using the 'therubyracer', 'react-rails', and 'sprockets-coffee-react' gems)

This is the code for my simple component (Hello.js.cjsx):

```
# @cjsx React.DOM

Hello = React.createClass(
  render: ->
    <div>
      Hello {@props.name || "World"}!
    </div>
)

window.components ?= {}
window.components.Hello = Hello
```

In my rails view (index.html.erb) this works just fine:

```
<%= render_component('components.Hello', {name: 'Jack'}) %>
```

However, when I try this:

```
<%= react_component('components.Hello', {name: 'Jill'}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

I get this error:

`Encountered error "ReferenceError: components is not defined"`

which seems odd because I'm defining it in my component.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's what it is. Undefined error. What is "?="?

Comment: The ?= is coffeescript's 'existential' operator. Its javascript equivalent is: if (window.components == null) { window.components = {}; }

Comment: I should add that changing that line to: window.components = {} Doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for anything rendered with `render_component` it's required that the component is registered with the global `window` object. This is kind of not ideal but just how it works for the time being.

This is what I've been doing. Not ideal, but helps.

```
components /
    namespace /
       MyComponent.js.jsx
```

Then doing this in my file:

```
# components/namespace/MyComponent.js.jsx

window.NamespaceMyComponent = React.createClass({});

module.exports = window.NamespaceMyComponent;
```

This last part allows me to use browserify and require my module like this:

`require('components/namespace/MyComponent')`

and using the `render_component` helper like this:

`<%= render_component "NamespaceMyComponent", {}, {prerender: true} %>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the syntax you used.
Please, replace the lines :

```
window.components ?= {}
window.components.Hello = Hello
```

with

```
window.Hello = Hello
```

(You can follow [this link](https://github.com/dobrite/cjsx-rails-example/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/car.js.coffee.cjsx) for further examples).

Comment: But how does that solve my issue of wanting to put all of my components in the same object namespace instead of making them all global?